# How to wrap all repository calls with an Around aspect

Tags: java, spring-data, aop, spring-aop

I would like to wrap all the repository calls in my service with an Around aspect for creating some metrics.

All of my `JpaRepositories` are annotated with `org.springframework.stereotype.Repository`, so I tried something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@Aspect
public class RepositoryMetrics {

    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)")
    public void logQueryTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //Some logic here
        joinPoint.proceed();
        //Some logic here
    }
}
```

But seems like the aspect method never runs. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the `JpaRepository` classes annotated as follows

```
@Repository
public interface JpaEmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<JpaEmployee, Long> {
...
}
```

Following Aspect would intercept all method calls happening to that class

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class RepositoryAspect {

    @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)")
    public void repositoryAnnotationPointCut() {}

    @Around("repositoryAnnotationPointCut()")
    public void logQueryTime(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("logged for "+pjp.toLongString());
        pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Please note that a Configuration class be better left for configuration entries and you may create a separate class for Aspect and annotate the same with `@Component` as given in the example.

Make sure you have `@ComponentScan` to auto detect the Aspect and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on the Configuration class. Something as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {RepositoryAspect.class})
public class AppConfig {
...
}
```

**Update**

Following are the reasons , your code didn't work as expected

1.

[Pointcut designator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) @annotation

> @annotation: Limits matching to join points where the subject of the
>   join point (**the method being executed in Spring AOP**) has the given
>   annotation.

In this case method is not annotated.

2.

The Configuration class `RepositoryMetrics` is not annotated with [@EnableAspectJAutoProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html) . I assume Spring AOP was not enabled in any of the Configuration classes.